Transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: tcp provider, error: 0 - no such file or directory)'
using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TMateriales (NumMateriales, CodMateriales, NamMateriales, IslocalPMateriales, IdCategries, IsDepoMateriales, MadMateriales, PriceMateriales, PricePecMateriales, IdCurrency, TotaAmountOfPiece, DatMateriales) VALUES (@NumMateriales, @CodMateriales, @NamMateriales, @IslocalPMateriales, @IdCategries, @IsDepoMateriales, @MadMateriales, @PriceMateriales, @PricePecMateriales, @IdCurrency, @TotaAmountOfPiece, @DatMateriales)", App.Connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumMateriales", row.NumMateriales ?? string.Empty);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodMateriales", row.CodMateriales ?? string.Empty);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NamMateriales", row.NamMateriales ?? string.Empty);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IslocalPMateriales", row.IslocalPMateriales ?? false);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCategries", row.IdCategries ?? 0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDepoMateriales", row.IsDepoMateriales ?? false);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MadMateriales", row.MadMateriales ?? string.Empty);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceMateriales", row.PriceMateriales ?? 0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PricePecMateriales", row.PricePecMateriales ?? 0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCurrency", row.IdCurrency ?? 0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotaAmountOfPiece", row.TotaAmountOfPiece ?? 0);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatMateriales", row.DatMateriales ?? DateTime.Now);

    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    return Task.FromResult(result != null ? Convert.ToInt32(result) : 0);
}

I try set PriceMateriales to zero is decimal type and these error happen

a transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: tcp provider, error: 0 - no such file or directory)

and same for PricePecMateriales.

Why are you using ExecuteScalar? I believe ExecuteNonQuery is the right method for an INSERT command.

You should check out Can we stop using AddWithValue() already? and stop using .AddWithValue() - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Your error could be because ExecuteScalar() expects a response, and an INSERT statement without an OUTPUT clause, or SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE statement following in the same transaction, does not have a return value.
But I would expect this to be a one off related to connection to the database server based on the specific error.
If your transport error continues to occur after correcting your code, check out this answer that outlines several ways to resolve connectivity between your appserver and database server:
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server
In either case, ExecuteScalar() is not going to return a value, so your logic will always return 0.
To correct your code, you have three options depending on your use case.  Where you are calling the method that executes the query may give some insight into what your use case actually is.
The first, as Dan Guzman points on in his comment, is to use ExecuteNonQuery.  This will fix your error, and returns the number of rows affected by the query.
The second is to add an OUTPUT clause to your statement and use ExecuteScalar(), and capture the returned output data.
The third still uses ExecuteScalar().  Append a SELECT statement to your INSERT.  Forexample:
command.CommandText += "; SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);";
Will then return only the identity value of the inserted row.  Great for INSERTing a single row, and allowing you to continue to work with the newly saved entity.

Are you 100% sure about that? I don't think you get a a transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server error in this situation. You would get a higher level error, if any.

Good point.  I would expect the transport error to be related to connectivity, and their result would simply be null.  Always returning 0 after their null check. I've changed the verbiage to remove the cause and effect assumption of that specific error.  The rest of the answer should help avoid additional issues related to the code.

@DaleK Pretty sure no error occurs at all, you just get a null (as opposed to DBNull.Value)

@Charlieface Thats what I expected :) but been a while
